# Do I need a Mexican visa with my US valid visa to travel to Mexico?

Tags: visas, mexico, tajikistani-citizens

I'm an international student in the US, and am traveling to Mexico on March 6th-12th. I'm a citizen of Tajikistan and have a friend from Russia who didn't need a Mexican visa with the valid student F-1 visa to travel to Mexico. I've been doing some research going to Mexican embassy for some info and asked my school adviser whether I need one he said yes, however, information on these web sites are confusing me: Take a close look at b) [COUNTRIES AND REGIONS THAT REQUIRE A VISA TO TRAVEL TO MEXICO](http://www.inm.gob.mx/index.php/page/paises_visa/en.html) On the other hand on the following link under the Requirements Tourist Visa to Travel to Mexico: 
[Requirements Tourist Visa to Travel to Mexico](http://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/seattle/index.php/visas-requirements) it's asking to bring a valid US visa to apply for the Mexican visa. While I was with J-1 in 2008 I did apply for the Mexican visa though and somebody else did the documentation on behalf of me. So this is my very first time applying by myself and am confused a bit. **Note:** I'm going to Cabo which doesn't do stamp by arrival. Thanks for the feedback in advance!

UPDATE: It looks like with the US visa stamp on a foreign passport we're not required to have a Mexican visa. I did travel to Los Cabos, Mexico and didn't have any visa trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your U.S. visa is still valid, then you don't need a visa to go to Mexico for visiting purposes for up to 180 days.

Comment: @user2486873: Well, doesn't the link you already have say this?