# Crossing the Mexican/US border with USA tourist visa

Tags: usa, borders, mexico, california, customs-and-immigration

I just got a USA tourist visa and I'm going to Mexico soon. I would like to know if I can cross the border to go to the USA (California), knowing that I have stated in my DS-160 form that I intended to go to New York.
Note that my question is about entering the USA not Mexico.

Comment: What is your citizen? I am Brazilian and I got an USA B1/B2 Visa to go to Iowa. However, after that I already have been in other states in US.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a Mexican visa with my US valid visa to travel to Mexico?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42942/do-i-need-a-mexican-visa-with-my-us-valid-visa-to-travel-to-mexico)

Comment: @Suncatcher thanks, but my question is about entering the US not mexico.

Comment: @MarcelP. I am algerian. But have you been first at Iowa with your visa ?

Comment: First time, it was Iowa. However, I already have been in NY, Chicago and so on...What you said in the interview is important, but plans could change and I am not seeing a big deal. Do you have a US Multiple Entry Visa?

Comment: @MarcelP. Yes, but I have never been in the USA yet.

Comment: I believe you will not face any issue. You need to have an explanation why to change your plans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you will not have any issue. You could apply for a Visa without any plan.

> Q: Is it mandatory to have a specific trip (itinerary) planned to get
>   visitor visa?  A: No, you can apply even if you have no definite plan
>   to immediately go on trip to U.S. You may intend to go  some later
>   date too. But if you are given 6 months visa, you have to go to U.S.
>   within next 6 months, else it will expire and you will have to apply
>   for new visa. If you get 10 years visa, it is not mandatory to go to
>   U.S. within a specified time period. You can go to the U. S. anytime
>   within next 10 years.

Source: [immiHelp](https://www.immihelp.com/visitor-visa/tourist-visa-faq.html)